# How to teach my ML model to extract needed information from text?

Tags: python, machine-learning, text-classification

I have Python code that train my ML model to recognize command like:

> > Turn on thi light
> > ========>LightOn

or

> > Turn off the music
> > ========>MusicOff

this is my small dataset:
[training_data.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKwZo.png)

And also this is what i used in my code:
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/text_analytics/working_with_text_data.html
Parameter tuning using grid search

The problem is that this model is classifier, while i need it to extract needed text from string, and to change them based on a context, for example:

if i load this dataset:[training_data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cyeIp.png), i want it to recognize my other command in the same way:

> Can you please find the resolution of my instagram post:
>
> > text:the resolution of instagram post

> What the algebra means:
>
> > the meaning of algebra

> how many dicroveries is made in archeology field:
>
> > how many dicroveries is made in archeology field:

> how steel is made:
>
> > how steel is made

> how to change binary to decimal
>
> > binary to decimal

Comment: SO is for programming question, design questions should be asked on https://datascience.stackexchange.com/. But this question is way too broad anyway,,. and a bit naive, I'm afraid: for this kind of 'virtual assistant' system to work properly, you would need to train it on thousands of queries at the very least. Training with a dozen examples is not useful, the model cannot generalize anything. Additionally this kind of system is much more complex than this: for example the model doesn't have any idea what is the resolution of an image, let alone how to obtain this information.

Comment: In short, you're assuming that your model will become intelligent, but it won't. Sadly, the hype around AI can make people believe in magic: there's no intelligent system of any kind, just good imitation systems well designed and well trained by large teams of well-paid experts at Google or Amazon... It's not that easy.